# Site won't center align in IE6

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

My site won't center align in IE6 for some reason. I cant understand why I'm sure I've done everything right but obviously not. The site is:

```
http://dreamdeals.rnmtest.co.uk/
```

Comment: It isn't center-aligned in Chrome also.

Comment: @casablanca What's your screen width? I have 1920px, and the main content is left-aligned.

Comment: Its centered in my chrome, what version are you using?

Comment: One thing to point out, you don't need the text-align center in the body and then text-align: left in your container. And try to work out why you have a massive scroll bar on the bottom. That could be your issue! You might want to consider externalising your javascript too

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Mine is 1366px, there's enough free space on the sides and the content is clearly centred both in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Not sure why mine is different. In Chrome 11 it is center aligned and in IE6 the ticker image sprites are not being clipped properly resulting in a [very wide layout](http://img851.imageshack.us/i/dreamdealsie6.png/).

Comment: @casablanca Never mind. The OP has updated the CSS code of the page in the last couple of minutes. It is centered now.

Comment: ah dint notice the massive horizontal scroll thanks for pointing that out

Comment: You shouldn't waste time on supporting IE6. In my humble opinion, this  browser is deprecated... After all, it is 10 years old (released on August 27, 2001)!

Comment: Site looks centred here in IE6, although the Music 'play' buttons etc are borked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your special offers container is overflowing in ie6. Try removing that container and see if it will center than. Otherwise try to fix it using `overflow:hidden` on the mentioned container.

Also the icons are showing the whole sprite you use.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an old trick to centre your site in IE6.

Set text-align: center; in the body. Remember to reset your main (wrapper/container) div with text-align: left;

The other (good) browsers should be handled by setting auto margins left and right.

Example:

```
body { width: 900px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; /* for IE6 */ }
#container { text-align: left; }
```

Comment: And it's not true in the slightest. IE < 6 needs this, but not IE6